# Php fatal error loading 'Mail/mimeDecode' even with php-pear install

Tags: php

I have centos machine where I have install using yum install php-pear. So I tried this in my php page

```
require_once 'Mail/RFC822.php';
require_once 'Mail/mimeDecode.php';
```

I get this error "`Warning: require_once(Mail/mimeDecode.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/pro1/ast/include.inc.php on line 36 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Mail/mimeDecode.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/pro1/ast/include.inc.php on line 36`". What else to be install ?

Comment: If you are able to answer your own question, please note the solution in a full answer (not just a link to the answer elsewhere), and mark it as such. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of the rest. Besides doing yum install php-pear. Next thing is this pear install Mail and finally you need  yum install php-pear-Mail-mimeDecode. So far this have helped me.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness sake, first install the **pear package**, then follow it up with **Mail** and **Mail_mime** as:

```
dnf install php-pear-Mail
pear install Mail Mail_Mime
```

This should work for CentoOS or Rocky Linux; use yum if dnf is not supported.